# Aguardar um evento ser disparado para continuar o processo C#

Tags: c#, eventos, assincronismo, navegador-de-internet

No método `RealizarPesquisa`, ao executar a linha `_WebBrowser.Navigate()`, é disparado o evento `DocumentCompleted()`, mas esse evento ele demora um pouco para ser executado, sendo assim, o método `RealizarPesquisa` continua seu processo e quando vou pegar o Document, ele está vindo nulo, porque o `eventoDocumentCompleted` ainda não foi concluído, tentei usar o `AutoResetEvent`, mas não obtive êxito, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

```
    public class GoogleSearch
{
    private WebBrowser _WebBrowser;
    private string _TituloPesquisa;
    private string _LinkPesquisa;
    private List<GoogleResultado> _GoogleResultadoList;

    static AutoResetEvent aguardarDocumentCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public GoogleSearch()
    {
        ConfigurarWebBrowser();
        _GoogleResultadoList = new List<GoogleResultado>();
    }

    public string GetResultJson 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _GoogleResultadoList.ToJsonSerialization<GoogleResultado>();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<GoogleResultado> GetListResults
    {
        get
        {
            return _GoogleResultadoList.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Pesquisar(string textoConsulta)
    {
        RealizarPesquisa(textoConsulta);             
    }

    private void _WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        aguardarDocumentCompleted.Set();

        if (_WebBrowser.Document != null)
        {
            // Resultado em Html - Obter as Divs onde ficam o resultado da pesquisa do google.
            HtmlElementCollection divs = _WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

            // Obter dados da pesquisa.
            _TituloPesquisa = _WebBrowser.Document.Title;
            _LinkPesquisa = _WebBrowser.Document.Url.ToString();

            GoogleResultado resultado;
            foreach (HtmlElement x in divs)
            {
                // Div onde fica o resultado das pesquisas do google.
                if (x.GetAttribute("className") == "g")
                {
                    HtmlElement link = x.GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    resultado = new GoogleResultado();
                    resultado.Titulo = link.InnerText;
                    resultado.Url = link.GetAttribute("href");
                    _GoogleResultadoList.Add(resultado);
                }
            }
        }           
    }

    private void ConfigurarWebBrowser()
    {
        _WebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        _WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += _WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
        _WebBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com.br", UriKind.Absolute);
    }

    private void RealizarPesquisa(string textoConsulta)
    {
        _WebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com.br/search?num=100&q=" + textoConsulta);

        aguardarDocumentCompleted.WaitOne();

        var document = _WebBrowser.Document;
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque nao coloca dentro do evento de completed?

Comment: Não posso fazer isso, pois preciso do documento no retorno do método RealizarPesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

Você fazer isso utilizando o `AutoResetEvent`, para esperar uma resposta do método `_WebBrowserDocumentCompleted`.

```
static AutoResetEvent esperar = new AutoResetEvent(true); //Instancia o AutoResetEvent

private void RealizarPesquisa(string textoConsulta)
{
    _WebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com.br/search?num=100&q=" + textoConsulta);

    esperar.WaitOne(); //Faz esperar uma resposta para continuar executando

    var document = _WebBrowser.Document;

}

private void _WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    esperar.Set(); //Da a resposta para continuar executando
    if (_WebBrowser.Document != null)
    {
        //Minimizei o código aqui no exemplo para ficar mais fácil de ver
    }           
}
```

Não se esqueça de colocar:

```
using System.Threading;
```

Veja mais sobre isso na [documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Testei por diversas vezes o jeito que você colocou e não obtive exito. Teria mais alguma coisa além disso ?

Comment: Tente trocar o true para false, no `new AutoResetEvent(true)`

Comment: Nada ainda Francisco, vou editar e colocar meu fonte pra você ver.